# Can't compile project because of wininet library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-libraries, wininet

I cloned a project from github to my computer and I'm trying to compile it but I'm getting a crazy amount of errors regarding references to libraries and stuff. I uploaded the project from another computer and it works just fine in that computer. Here are the errors I'm getting:

[image]

There are more errors but these are enough. As you can see the issue is within the included libraries (which are static), so I'm not sure what I'm missing here, because the linking to the wininet library and such are fine.

Maybe its an inconsistency between x86 and x64? I dunno.

The path to the c++ compiler:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-5.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev0\mingw32\bin\c++.exe

Path to library

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-5.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v4-rev0\mingw32\include\wininet.h

I followed these steps to configure this environment:
-Downloaded netbeans
-Downloaded mingwin
-Downloaded msys

Its weird because when ctrl + click the wininet.h and variable types and everything it directs me to where they're declared, however the environment can't locate them.

If you need more information please tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of posting images of text, post the text itself. But in this case, don't do that either, first google the actual errors.

Comment: you need to link you project to WinInet library

Comment: @DavidHaim: true, but that only becomes relevant once the code compiles. So far it doesn't even reach the linking phase.

Comment: @MSalters I did google the errors but got no solution. and I did link the project to the wininet library.

Comment: I cannot help but wonder. Copy & Paste of the actual text is *easier* than taking a screenshot. How come so many people think a screenshot is a good idea?

Comment: @DevSolar So it looks good and formatted; if you copy-paste its kind of blurry all the text and stuff. Plus, with the snipping tool its way easier than copypasting + formatting

Comment: @Víctor: How do *you* know what looks "good" and what looks "blurry" *to me*? How do you even know my screen resolution? The way SO renders the page for me, the text in your screenshot is 1/2 my preferred text size, clunky, and next to illegible. Even clicking on the pic to show it seperately still gives me 3/4th of *my* preferred size. **Please do post text, not screenshots of text.**

Comment: @DevSolar I know I prefer screenshots to a crazy amount of unreadable unformatted text, I was just acting upon the rule "treat others the way you want to be treated" but whatever floats your boat, next time I'll post the text directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "the WinInet" library that you can download. This is all part of the Windows SDK. `LPVOID` for instance is defined after you include `<windows.h>`

Comment: This answer is right. After including windows.h before wininet the errors disappear. I'm getting other error now but this one was solved. I find it really strange because in my other computer the code compiles and it does not need any extra include. Anyway, thankyou very much.

Comment: @Víctor: It's not unusual for some headers to include other headers. If this is not documented, you should treat it as an implementation detail that can change. E.g.wininet.h is not documented to include windows.h. If you have two different Windows SDK versions, this could differ.